# Using a function inside a function instead of a lambda

Tags: python, function

I wasn't sure whether to post this on stackoverflow or programmers, so sorry if I picked the wrong one. I'm also very new to python, so I might be missing something.

Which one of these is more correct. As in, which one is the best practice. Are both? If so, which one do I use when.

1) Lambda:

```
def hello_world():
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: print("Hello World"))
```

2)Function inside a function

```
def hello_world():
    def hello():
        print("Hello World")
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=hello)
```

Comment: Both a perfectly fine. Just a matter of taste.

Comment: Use the `def` if the expression is complicated and should be written in more than on line. The `lambda` otherwise(at least this is how I usually write).

Comment: I wouldn't use the `lambda` here as it has a side effect (namely, output) and I tend to expect lambda functions not to have any.

Comment: For this case, you can also put the function outside the function.

Comment: @DSM The trouble is that, in a language like Python, lambdas (or any other functions) with no side effects are not terribly useful. In GUI programming lambdas are typically used for constructing callbacks, which typically function by side effect. For example, `self.button.connect('clicked', lambda btn: self._start_calculation(current, num))`.

Comment: @user4815162342: almost all of my uses of lambda functions have no side effects, and for that matter, most of them are pure.  I don't think "tend to expect" rules out that there are situations where a different policy makes more sense.

Comment: @DSM Fair enough - guess I've been doing GUI callbacks for too long.

Comment: @user4815162342 this is the kind of thing i use them for too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are perfectly acceptable.

Just keep in mind that the nested function will be able to evolve into something more complex, while the lambda is forever limited to a single expression.